# Karate DSL setting date in payload includes escape characters for slash

Tags: karate

In a karate test scenario, I would need to update date element value in the json payload.

I tried using set by generating the date that was returned by an js function. However when executed the payload has date with escape character for slash

```
Scenario: Set due date and validate the response has the updated due date
    * def futureDate =
    """
    function() {
      var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
      var Calendar = Java.type('java.util.Calendar');
      var currCalIns = Calendar.getInstance();
      currCalIns.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, +5);
      var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
      return sdf.format(currCalIns.getTime());
    }
    """
    * def date = futureDate()
    Given path '/payment/reminder'
    And def payload = read('test_payload.json')
    And set payload.due_date = date
    And request getRequestBody
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    And match response[0] contains { name: 'foo', value: 'bar', domain: '.abc.com' }
```

Payload test_payload.json has following json

```
{
    "payment": [
      "#(paymentId)"
    ],
    "due_date": null,
    "edited_by": {
      "user_id": "125a2895-ebfe-4cd4-bdef-310eece90809",
      "user_name": "TestUser1"
    }
  }
```

When the scenario is executed, the payload contains "due_date": 11/30/2023 instead of  "due_date": 11/30/2023